# Make uploading a file required for creation of users and contacts

Tags: contact, user-management, file-storage, google-drive

I am using salesforce to create portal for a school. I am using students and parents as contacts and staff as users. When I am creating students I need to make it manadatory to collect certain documents. For example: for a KG kid I need to collect birth cirtificate or passport copy. And in case of grade 1 or higher I need to collect Transfer cirtificate in addition to standard Date of birth and ID proof. I see a option to attach documents to contact is there a way to link and mandate these documents? Also can I directly save them to google drive since we have limited space on salesforce wheareas the amount of space ,on google drive, is unlimited for educational institutions.

Also incase of users I want to lock their accounts until required documents are submited. I am also building recruitment module so once they are hires I want to create users autmatically. But I want to make sure their account will not be active until their documents are submited.

THe best solution I came up with is creating a seprate table and having picklist for type of document and upload with rich text field. Is there a better standard to do it?

Comment: mandatory upload of docs with creation of Contact - one option is custom VF page that overrides New button for Contact

Comment: I am not comfortable with Apex yet. I dont mind doing it if it is the last option

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution that I know of for someone who doesn't code would be to install [Picture Uploader](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016YT5EAM) from the App Exchange (it's Free) and then go to 
[How to Update Picture Uploader to Work with Your Custom Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/labs/2010/07/how-to-update-picture-uploader-for-use-with-your-custom-object.html) to get the code you can use to add your documents to a related custom object on which you could create categories like "Transfer certificate", etc which you could set as required fields for different types of new student contacts. I suggest you consider using Publisher or Record Actions to simplify doing this so the fields will be pre-populated.

If you don't attach these to a custom object, you may be limited as to how many images you can upload to a contact record. That's legwork you'll need to sort out for yourself, but hopefully this will at least get you started. At a minimum, you'll need to create the additional fields on your contact object which you can relate to a custom object as look-ups if necessary.

Comment: Is it possible with apex or workflows to mandate?

Comment: You could create a VisualFlow that would take someone through an "interview" of sorts or a decision tree type of thing that required them to upload various documents and complete certain fields when creating a new type of contact which the flow could determine based on the answers to the questions. You could add validation rules to make certain the files had been uploaded before a record could be saved.